# Wireguard client incoming packets drop

Tags: networking, firewall, vpn, wireguard

I have a home server running Ubuntu Server. I'm running some services on docker which need a VPN client for anonymity. The wireguard client runs as a standalone application. I'm running traefik to access the services with SSL wich works fine.

**Additional information**:

- The `eth0` IP is `192.168.178.101`
- The docker network are on the subnet range `172.xx.xx.xx/16`
- Port 80 and 443 are port forwarded for traefik.

When I enable the VPN everything works as expected with the exception from the incoming WAN data. The services are only accessable when I'm on the LAN. When a request is originating from the WAN (behind the router) the packets are dropped.

**The wireguard client configuration is as follows:**

```ini
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
Address = 10.64.154.19/32
DNS = 10.64.0.1

PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.178.0/32 -o wg0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:51820
```

- I did a `tcpdump` with port 443 as filter which results in a length=0.
- I did take a look at the `iptables` but it looks fine to me.
- I tried adding `AllowedIP`s with the subnet of `eth0` and docker which did not resolve the problem.
- When i disable the wireguard client everthing works fine like before.

Any idea what can be the problem? I'm not a professional networking engineer maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Do an `echo "module wireguard +p" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control` as root, on both the client and the server, then watch `dmesg` for any "packet not allowed"-like messages?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i did echo it and checked if it went well with the cat command and the echo was succesfull. Unfortunately no error messages popped up in the dmesg. I think it has something to do with the firewall right?

Comment: My wild guess. By default in this configuration, wg-quick installs policy routing rules so all traffic uses the VPN. WAN being with the default route, it won't work because now the default route is for the VPN. More policy routing + dual-homing setup is needed. But integration with Docker will make it harder. This kind of problem needs reproducibility. But if Docker is part of the reproduction, that's just too much to handle.

Comment: @A.B So i did some more searching on this subject. I found out on this website [link](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/01/wg-quick-firewall-rules) that if i add the option Table = off to the wg configuration that the default firewall rules got disabled which resulted in a positive result for me. But there was one problem...
Now the traffic uses the default route on the eth0 interface which is not usefull. I did check if the VPN does work with ip check via the wg0 interface which resulted in the VPN public IP address.